# Using re- regular expression twice

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use re twice to search and split data
For example:

```
[2018-07-10 15:04:11] USER INPUT "hello"
[2018-07-10 15:04:12] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Hello! How are you doing today"
[2018-07-10 15:04:42] USER INPUT "I am doing good thank you"
[2018-07-10 15:04:42] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Good to know"
```

I am finding all the substring within []

```
2018-07-10 15:04:11,
2018-07-10 15:04:12,
2018-07-10 15:04:42,
2018-07-10 15:04:42,
```

I am trying to split the space

```
2018-07-10,15:04:11,2018-07-10,15:04:12,2018-07-10,15:04:42,2018-07-10,15:04:42
```

and my code is:

```
import re

file = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', file)
m = re.split(r'\ +', file)
```

but it's giving me an error- and not letting me use re twice

any suggestions would be great! Thank you in advance

Comment: You should really post the error, which I'm guessing is that you can't split a list, which is what `re.findall` returns

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: As a note, regex isn't needed twice here. You can just use `.split()`

Comment: I am sorry- there's no error. It just did not print!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your regex to capture each group the first time, no need for **`split`** at all:

```
re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\s(.*?)\]', s)

[('2018-07-10', '15:04:11'),
 ('2018-07-10', '15:04:12'),
 ('2018-07-10', '15:04:42'),
 ('2018-07-10', '15:04:42')]
```

If you need this as a flattened list:

```
[elem for grp in re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\s(.*?)\]', s) for elem in grp]

['2018-07-10',
 '15:04:11',
 '2018-07-10',
 '15:04:12',
 '2018-07-10',
 '15:04:42',
 '2018-07-10',
 '15:04:42']
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a ton! I needed a flattened list!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> sum([date.split() for date in re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', file)], [])
['2018-07-10', '15:04:11', '2018-07-10', '15:04:12', '2018-07-10', '15:04:42', '2018-07-10', '15:04:42']
```

Or using `itertools.chain`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*re.findall(r'\[(\S+) (\S+)\]', file)))
['2018-07-10', '15:04:11', '2018-07-10', '15:04:12', '2018-07-10', '15:04:42', '2018-07-10', '15:04:42']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

data = """[2018-07-10 15:04:11] USER INPUT "hello"
[2018-07-10 15:04:12] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Hello! How are you doing today"
[2018-07-10 15:04:42] USER INPUT "I am doing good thank you"
[2018-07-10 15:04:42] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Good to know"
"""

new_data = []
re.sub(r'\[(.*?)\].*', lambda g: new_data.extend(g[1].split()), data)
print(','.join(new_data))
```

Outputs:

```
2018-07-10,15:04:11,2018-07-10,15:04:12,2018-07-10,15:04:42,2018-07-10,15:04:42
```

Comment: I really, really do not like abusing `re.sub` to cause side-effects here.  A simple loop would be so much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall()` and `.split()` since it's not necessary to use regex twice.

```
import re
a = '''[2018-07-10 15:04:11] USER INPUT "hello"
[2018-07-10 15:04:12] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Hello! How are you doing today"
[2018-07-10 15:04:42] USER INPUT "I am doing good thank you"
[2018-07-10 15:04:42] SYSTEM RESPONSE: "Good to know"'''


[item for sublist in [n.split() for n in re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]',a)] for item in sublist]
['2018-07-10',
 '15:04:11',
 '2018-07-10',
 '15:04:12',
 '2018-07-10',
 '15:04:42',
 '2018-07-10',
 '15:04:42']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `file` variable has a list of elements from `re.findall`

**Try:**

```
import re

file = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', file)
m = [re.split(r'\ +', i) for i in file]
print(m)
```

**Output:**

```
[['2018-07-10', '15:04:11'], ['2018-07-10', '15:04:12'], ['2018-07-10', '15:04:42'], ['2018-07-10', '15:04:42']]
```